# Strange cast in Equals override provided by MSDN

Tags: c#, casting

I am looking at the article from MSDN [Guidelines for Overloading Equals() and Operator ==](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx)

and I saw the following code

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    // If parameter is null return false.
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // If parameter cannot be cast to Point return false.
    TwoDPoint p = obj as TwoDPoint;
    if ((System.Object)p == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Return true if the fields match:
    return (x == p.x) && (y == p.y);
}
```

the strange thing is the cast to object in the second if

```
// If parameter cannot be cast to Point return false.
TwoDPoint p = obj as TwoDPoint;
if ((object)p == null)
{
    return false;
}
```

Why p is casted again to object? Isn't it enough to write this

```
// If parameter cannot be cast to Point return false.
TwoDPoint p = obj as TwoDPoint;
if (p == null)
{
    return false;
}
```

If p cannot be casted to TwoDPoint, then it's value will be null. I am puzzled, probably I don't understand something trivial ...

**EDIT**

One more such cast is presented in the other Equals method

```
public bool Equals(TwoDPoint p)
{
    // If parameter is null return false:
    if ((object)p == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here again it's enough to check only `if(p == null)`

Comment: This is a code smell. They should have used ReferenceEquals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(object)p == null` uses the built-in `==` operator that in this case checks for reference equality. `p == null` would call an overloaded `operator==` for the specified type. If the overloaded `operator==` would be implemented in terms of `Equals` (it's not, in the sample you link to), then you'd have infinite recursion. Even if it's not implemented in terms of `Equals`, it would still do more than needs to be done.

Answer (score 4):

Just to complete both answers, the documentation you looked at is outdated as stated on the top of the page. If you look at the [newer guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173147(v=vs.90).aspx), there is a note which explains exactly why that is being done:

> A common error in overloads of operator == is to use (a == b), (a ==
>   null), or (b == null) to check for reference equality. **This instead
>   creates a call to the overloaded operator ==, causing an infinite
>   loop.** Use ReferenceEquals or cast the type to Object, to avoid the
>   loop.

Basically, doing so is equal to using [`object.ReferenceEquals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.object.referenceequals(v=vs.90).aspx), which is what the code is actually trying to do:

```
TwoDPoint p = obj as TwoDPoint;
if (object.ReferenceEquals(p, null))
{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is to ensure that the called == operator is the default implementation from Object, not the user-defined one. It is a common error to introduce unbounded recursion in code like this by having your own operators call themselves.